# Output blog posts only onto a part of webpage

Tags: php, wordpress

By default, blog posts can be shown on single page.
i want to customize a front page and display the posts only on the part of my page.
If it's possible, how can i output my latest blogposts onto a custom div or element?

Comment: What have you tried? How didn't that work? Is there any code? If not, why are you asking on a programming site? If so, what is it? Can you give us an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at least clarify exactly what you're asking?

Comment: i want it for my custom blog pages, i don't know exactly which function is used to output the posts. i'm asking this on a programming site because i want to know which php function do i need. MilanG answered my question already.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom loop, something like this:

http://www.johnmorrisonline.com/how-to-create-a-custom-loop-in-wordpress-using-wp_query/

So, basically use that WP_Query to get list of post and loop trough it:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Here is an example how I do it:

```
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => 3,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => 6,
    'category_name'    => '',
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'include'          => '',
    'exclude'          => '',
    'meta_key'         => '',
    'meta_value'       => '',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_mime_type'   => '',
    'post_parent'      => '',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );
    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

//  print_r($posts_array);
    foreach($posts_array as $current_post){
     print_r($current_post); // here you have current post values
    }
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

Comment: Could you post the relevant excerpts from the pages you linked so that if the sites ever go down or move, this answer is still helpful?